# Actualizar Crashlytics de Fabric a Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

Estuve actualizando la librería de Crashlytics de fabric a Firebase, la verdad que no conozco mucho de fabric, siempre he trabajado mis analytics con firebase. Mi duda es si el siguiente código

```
final Fabric fabric = new Fabric.Builder(this)
                .kits(new Crashlytics())
                .build();

Fabric.with(fabric);

Crashlytics.setString(BuildConfig.CRASHLYTICS_ENV_NAME, BuildConfig.CRASHLYTICS_ENV_NAME);
```

Solo debería cambiarse por:

```
FirebaseCrashlytics crashlytics = FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance();
crashlytics.setCustomKey(BuildConfig.CRASHLYTICS_ENV_NAME, BuildConfig.CRASHLYTICS_ENV_NAME);
```

Lo que he logrado ver es que el `setCustomKey` de firebase reemplaza al `setString` de fabric, sin embargo toda la instancia de fabric en firebase es necesario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varios cambios que debes realizar para migrar de `Fabric` a `Firebase Crashlytics` tu aplicación:

Primeramente agrega tu app a Firebase en la consola Firebase

https://console.firebase.google.com/

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Segundo, integra el SDK , dentro de tu `app/build.gradle` agrega la definición del plugin y la dependencia ( la versión apropiada a tu configuración)

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

...
...
...

// Add the Firebase Crashlytics SDK.
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.2.1'
```

En tu Activity "Launcher" define una variable de tipo FirebaseAnalytics

```
private FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;
```

y dentro de onCreate( ) inicializa FirebaseAnalytics:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);


   }
```

Es importante [Probar tu implementación de Crashlytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation?platform=android) para asegurar se implemento correctamente en tu app.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation?platform=android

---

Con respecto a tu pregunta: "Lo que he logrado ver es que el setCustomKey de firebase reemplaza al setString de fabric, sin embargo toda la instancia de fabric en firebase es necesario?"

La respuesta es sí, [considerando debería existir una inicialización de tipo singleton](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/crashlytics/FirebaseCrashlytics) en realidad esta llamada

```
FirebaseCrashlytics crashlytics = FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance();
```

es la que obtiene la instancia singleton. Yo también desearía no tener que definirla en cada Activity :-(.

---

Las instrucciones para realizar la migración es tan especificadas en la documentación:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/migration-post-linking

Answer (score 0):

La instancia es necesaria por que de `FirebaseCrashlytics crashlytics` utilizas `setCustomKey()`

Y de tu otra duda si estas en la correcta implementación, asi es, siguiendo la documentación oficial, estas en lo correcto

Doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?hl=es-419&platform=android