# ¿Como obtener/visualizar pila de errores de aplicacion Android?

Tags: java, android

¿Como puedo visualizar los 'crash' de mi aplicacion de Android sin estar conectado mediante el modo de depuracion?

Comment: es [esto](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics) lo que estás buscando?

Comment: Recuerda que es importante agregar lo que trataste o investigaste, con respecto a tu pregunta existe información en el sitio https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/425186/actualizar-crashlytics-de-fabric-a-firebase  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/110391/qu%c3%a9-es-crashlytics-de-fabric-y-c%c3%b3mo-configurarlo-para-android

Comment: @SinneroftheSystem Gracias por tu ayuda, era eso lo que buscaba.

Comment: Tambien gracias al incansable @Jorgesys que le veo ayudando a muchos. Un saludo.

Comment: Saludos @Master

Comment: Hola @Master, veo que el sistema te bloqueo, al parecer realizaste otras preguntas que no fueron bien recibidas, como moderadores no podemos quitar el bloqueo, te sugiero que si en esta publicación encontraste lo que buscabas la elimines o la edites, recuerda siempre realizar preguntas en base a [ask], agregar lo que trataste o investigaste ,saludos!